# Relationship between GIT and coarse moduli spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, moduli-space, geometric-invariant-theory

I'm trying to understand how a generic algebraic geometer constructs coarse moduli spaces.  I'm familiar with the definition, and how it is usually quite involved to show that a space has the coarse moduli property.  It seems that Mumfords GIT takes care of this somehow, although it seems to me that GIT is a way to construct 'nice' quotients.  How does this interact with the moduli property?

Comment: Is a generic algebraic geometer an algebraic geometer over the generic point?

Comment: I usually think about GIT quotients in the affine case, in which case 

https://sites.math.washington.edu/~jarod/papers/gms.pdf

and

https://sites.math.washington.edu/~jarod/papers/adequate.pdf

in which case Theorems 13.2 and 9.1.4 show that GIT quotients are good/adequate moduli spaces. These are teh generalizations of coarse moduli spaces to the case of Artin stacks (opposed to Deligne--Mumford). In the first article there is also a discussion of what happens in the general case.

Comment: generalization of coarse moduli spaces to the case of Artin stacks *and positive characteristic*.